# SVG Make a Circle Spin about its Center

Tags: html, svg

I have been trying to make a wheel that spins about its center. So far I can get it to orbit a point out of the circle. Please help!

Comment: How much help do you expect w/ code no-one here has seen?

Comment: Please include a [MCVE].

Comment: Also note that this is a common question. The solution to your problem is almost certainly available on here if you do a search.